# Placing a Quartz Scheduler in Stand-by Mode

Tags: java, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

You can place a Quartz scheduler in stand-by mode. During this time all triggers will not fire neither jobs being executed. But what happend if the standby(); command comes up during a job that is in the middle of its execution, let's say it is in the middle of writing a file?

example:

*// start() was previously invoked on the scheduler

scheduler.standby();

// now the scheduler will not fire triggers / execute jobs

// ...

scheduler.start();

// now the scheduler will fire triggers and execute jobs*

Answer (score 4):

I believe calling standby() will only stop further execution of triggers, it will not stop or abort any jobs that are already executing.